# How to validate a field only if an option is selected - RAILS 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

could one kindly advise me how i validate a field only if an option is selected

- so i have the selector that has the options: `parent` & `service provider`
- when `service provider` is selected the hidden selector `services` is displayed
- i want to validate the presences of `services` only when `service provider` is selected (not when `parent` is selected) as per image

will it be written something like the below:
`validates_presence_of :category_service_id, presence: true, if: :category_segment_id?, message: "can't be blank`"

could one kindly advise me on this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're very close. What you need to do is make a conditional validation (More about it [in the official guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation)).

You'd need to do the following:

```
validates_presence_of :category_service_id, if: :service_provider?

# Marking the validation check method as private is optional, but recommended
private

def service_provider?
  <Your code to check if segment is service_provider comes here>
end
```

`message` is not required since the default error message would be `can't be blank`.

I would highly recommend reading the doc mentioned in the link above for a better understanding of validations.

NOTE: `service_provider?` method is not required in case you're using enums to decide between `service_provider` and `parent` since enums define `option?` methods by default.